# Fire function when Stripe has error in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments

I am trying to fire a custom function when a credit card error occurs in the WooCommerce checkout flow.

I seem to be able to get standard woo errors by using but it seems that the stripe plugin does not us woocommerce_add_error

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_error', 'my_woocommerce_add_error' );
```

I found the following hook in the WooCommerce Stripe [documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/stripe/), but I can't seem to get it to work with add_action

> wc_gateway_stripe_process_payment_error ($error, $order) – Called when
>   an error occurs during the process payment event.

```
add_action( 'wc_gateway_stripe_process_payment_error', 'test_this' );
```

What am I missing? Is there another filter or hook that I should be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per documentation https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/stripe/ this hook take 2 params $error, $order so you have to tell it to WordPress:

```
add_action( 'wc_gateway_stripe_process_payment_error', 'test_this', 10, 2 );
function test_this($error, $order) {
// something
}
```

It's working fine on my side

Comment: Works perfectly! I was missing the priority. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I am currently trying to do something similar, except that I want to send an error message to the normal woocommerce error location... But somehow the code does not work... Any idea why? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63472812/how-to-display-woocommerce-stripe-error-message-next-to-woocommerce-normal-error)

- Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could figure out how to do this is by watching for dod inserts on the dom. This is the code I used below.

Note: You should probably use mutated events these days but for some reason, I couldn't figure it out.

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
  if ( $(e.target).hasClass('woocommerce-error') ) {
    console.log('stripe input error');         
   }
 });
```