# How to display Woocommerce stripe error message next to woocommerce normal error messages?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments, hook-woocommerce

How can I display the Woocommerce stripe Gateway error messages next to the normal error messages (for example next to the "First Name validation" error message...?

That error message should be displayed like picture (2)
[image]

[image]

I've tried to hook it to wc_gateway_stripe_process_payment_error but it doesn't work.

```html
add_action( 'wc_gateway_stripe_process_payment_error', 'test_this', 10, 2 );
function test_this($error, $order) {
$woocommerce->add_error( __( 'Your Credit card details are wrong.', 'woocommerce' ) );

}
```

Comment: Based on the docs for adding actions (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) and WooCommerce's action hooks docs (https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/stripe/#action-hooks), your code should work. Does the hook not get fired at all? Or is it that the $woocommerce->add_error throws an error?

Comment: I think the hook does not get fired at all... Tried to make a alert instead of the error message but that doesn't worked eighter...

add_action( 'wc_gateway_stripe_process_payment_error', 'test_this', 10, 2 );
function test_this($error, $order) {
?> 
<script type='text/javascript'> 
         $(document).ready(function(){
               alert("Yeah!");
};
</script>
<?php 
}

Comment: as far as I can tell that should work. It might be worthwhile opening up an issue on the woocommerce/woocommerce-gateway-stripe repo to get their take: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-gateway-stripe/issues