# How to run Javascript / Jquery when Woocommerce / Stripe checkout fails?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, woocommerce, stripe-payments

Seems like when I use Stripe plugin for payments, the `checkout_error` event does not happen when a card error occurs. (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/342148/list-of-js-events-in-the-woocommerce-frontend)

Looking through Stripe documentation, it seems like when a credit card gets rejected by Stripe, there is a 402 error. I would like to run a Javascript / Jquery code when this happens.

**What I have tried**

According to this post ([Fire function when Stripe has error in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55956652/fire-function-when-stripe-has-error-in-woocommerce)) this is the code I could try:

```
add_action( 'wc_gateway_stripe_process_payment_error', 'test_this', 10, 2 );
function test_this($error, $order) {
$variable = "card error";
echo "<script>console.log('$variable');</script>";
}
```

**Problem**

However, nothing shows up in my console log when there is a card error.

Thank you!